# WCF binding attributes not being pulled into my client service reference

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, wcf-binding

I'm having a problem getting my binding attributes to be pulled into my client service config.  I'm running a WCF service (as a Windows Service) on a server.  I first tried naming the binding, and applying it to my service with the bindingConfiguration attribute, but that didn't work.  I saw that other people made the binding their default by removing the name attribute, so that's where I'm at now.  The app config for the WCF project looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="6553600" maxBufferSize="6553600" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client />
    <services>
        <service ... />
        <service name="PdfWriterService.Service4">
          <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://rsmreports:8733/PdfWriterService/v4" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="PdfWriterService.IService4">
          <!-- 
                          Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
                          identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
                          automatically.
                    -->
          <!--<identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>-->
        </endpoint>
        <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
        <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. -->
        <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
                      set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
                      set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
                      to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

and my web.config on my client site (the Service portion) looks like this:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_PdfWriterServiceV4" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://rsmreports:8733/PdfWriterService/v4"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_PdfWriterServiceV4"
        contract="PdfWriter.PdfWriterServiceV4" name="BasicHttpBinding_PdfWriterServiceV4" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Is there something I'm missing getting the client to have those attributes (maxReceivedMessageSize and maxBufferSize)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that in order to use those properties, I needed to change the value both on the app.config of the service, as well as the web.config of the client site.  This is how I was able to get the changes to work.

If I'm not correct in my assumption that it's required, please let me know how to have those changes filter down into the client through updating the service reference, and I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: I'm having the same problem...did you find a resolution?